# Android app using java Webview container - Push notifications to device

Tags: java, android, webview, push-notification

I have an Android app that I have created using the Java Webview.  The app resides on a website and right now is pretty basic.  I am wondering how or if it is possible to send Push notifications to the device?  I am using the most current SDK and the Eclipse IDE.